# Fetch data from JSON and pass it as argument to function in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, rest

I'm following [this example](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/576246/A-Shopping-Cart-Application-Built-with-AngularJS) and in my scenario I want to get data from a JSON file instead of local data.
Given

```
    function store() {
       this.products = [
           new product("APL", "Apple", "Eat one every day to keep the doctor away!", 12, 90, 0, 2, 0, 1, 2),
           new product("AVC", "Avocado", "Guacamole anyone?", 16, 90, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2)
       ];
    }

    store.prototype.getProduct = function (sku) {
        for (var i = 0; i < this.products.length; i++) {
            if (this.products[i].sku == sku)
                return this.products[i];
        }

        return null;
    }
```

I have a simple file named "Product.json" and I want to Pull all my data from there and change nothing else.

Comment: You'll likely run into issues trying to "load" a file. You'll either need to just add the json data (copy/paste) into the angular code file or you'll need to expose some sort of service to provide the access to the data then grab it via AJAX. It seems like it should be a simple thing, but there are security concerns that make this a non-trivial thing.

Comment: You might have visited the link already so could you please please point me out to some link or something cuz im blind here..or maybe an example of Service to use to expose data!

Comment: I am of the opinion that it is always better to start easy then build. To start with, just copy the json data and paste it into your angular js code file and assign it to a var: `var data = {...}`. Then just work with the `data` var (or whatever you choose to name it). Once you get that working, _then_ worry about using a service to expose that data, and from there it is easy to use the service to call out to get data via ajax or whatever. Baby steps. :)

Comment: I've done that, copying data and all. Data in JSON is much more and simply copying all that in angular code would be a mess and would kill the soul of it, please write me a service module as you are trying to explain. Angular thing is really new to me but I want to learn more and carry on..thank you for your patience!!

Comment: You should worry less about "kill(ing) the soul" and more about understanding how it would work. Get it to work first _then_ worry about making it better/prettier. I gave you my opinion on how to approach the problem, it is up to you to choose to take the advice or not. I am not going to do the work for you, sorry...

Answer (score 0):

If you have your products.json file already you can use angular $http service to retrieve the data. Something like this:

```
$http.get('products.json').success(function(data){
   $scope.products = data;
});
```

EDIT:
In your case you would have to assign the data retrieved from the get request to your store.products array.

```
$http.get('Products.json').success(function(data) {
    store.products = data;
});
```

Comment: Would getting data this way fulfill this function's request ?

Comment: store.prototype.getProduct = function (sku) {
    for (var i = 0; i < this.products.length; i++) {
        if (this.products[i].sku == sku)
            return this.products[i];
    }